# byte array over $_GET request feasibility?

Tags: php, url, get, arrays, transmission

I hope this will be a relatively quick question.

If i send a byte array via the URL and retrieve it from a $_GET request in PHP server side scripts will the url be capable of transmitting the byte array? Is a  URL capable of being long enough for this purpose? or do i need another way to transmit the byte array?

example of what im attempting: `http://www.website.com/scrypt.php?image="bytearray"`

better yet is there a best practices for transmitting this data from say an Android app to php?

Comment: base64encode it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it doesn't exceed the [limit for a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string) or contain reserved characters that would be interpreted by the CGI...you're all set.  Go for it.